# Form submission problem in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building a simple mobile app using JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap and I've run into problems on my first form without even adding any logic!

So far the app just has a home page with a link to a simple 'new account' form. Here's the relevant JQuery Mobile marked-up HTML:

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#newAccountPage" data-role="button">New Account</a> 
    </div>

</div>

<div id="newAccountPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Add New Account</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="newAccountContent" data-role="content">
        <form id="newAccountForm" action="#" method="post">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="accountCode">Account Code</label> 
            <input id="accountCode" name="account-code" type="text"/>                           
            <label for="accountDesc">Description</label>  
            <textarea id="accountDesc" cols="40" rows="10" name="account-desc"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="buttonDiv" align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="New" data-inline="true"/>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- newAccountContent --> 
</div> <!-- newAccount -->
```

This all works fine in a browser and on the iPhone simulator with PhoneGap (in the sense that the page transition from home page to form works and when I click the submit button the app reverts to the home page).

However when I run this on the iPhone device itself, the form submission generates an "Error Loading Page" error message on the device and the form page stays put.

I'm sure this relates to a blindingly obvious error but it has me stumped as a newcomer. I suspect it is something to do with the way JQuery Mobile handles form submission on the device but it seems strange that there is no error on the simulator.

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it for you, but I think your problem is that you try to use POST in the form.
How is the phonegap supposed to serve a http POST?

Answer (score 1):

try to add jQuery code for handling form submition inside of function that is called after phonegap is loaded - onBodyLoad() or something similar . e.g.:

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function() {
           var params = $('#your-form-id').serializeArray();

           //you can either send the data to remote server
           $.post(http://localhost/myserver,params, function(){
                    alert("sending data");
           });
           //or you can process it on client side
           //which would require storing data inside of some storage etc.
});
```

generally there aren't many debuging messages when using phonegap, try to use js function

> console.log(some_object);

and have a look at weinre (http://muellerware.org/papers/weinre/manual.html)